# Angular JS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am starting to learn AngularJS and, following [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutoria) tutorial, I start my own application.

I have one error in controller.js that I don't know how to solve, I don't see what's wrong! :(.

Here is my **controller.js**:

```
var recetCtrl = angular.module('RecetaControllers' []);
recetCtrl.controller('RecetaListCtrl', [$scope, $http, 
    function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('json/recetas.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.recetas =  data;
        }); 
        $scope.orderProp = 'abc';
    }
]);
recetCtrl.controller('RecetaDetailCtrl', [$scope, $http, $routeProvider, 
    function($scope, $http, $routeProvider){
        $http.get('json/' + $routeParams.idReceta + '.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.receta = data;
        });
    }
]);
```

**EDIT:** The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by [identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need comma:

```
var recetCtrl = angular.module('RecetaControllers', []);
```

The next thing you need to update is to add quotes around your dependencies in controller declaration:

```
recetCtrl.controller('RecetaListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', // <- added quotes
    function($scope, $http){
        // your code
    }
]);
recetCtrl.controller('RecetaDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeProvider', // <- added quotes
    function($scope, $http, $routeProvider){
        // your code
    }
]);
```

Comment: sometimes the directive is not imported correctly that's why you get unexpected token..... That was problem with me.